# htaccess rule for specific query string

Tags: string, .htaccess, typo3

I've got a little Problem...

I have a Customer Page which uses bove http and https Protocoll (dont ask me why they do this^^). So https for forms and for the rest http.

Now they use a ajax request to a specific query string (index.php?type=4503469435) and this presents a crawled Weather Info.

There is a redirect for some https pages to redirect back to http...on form pages the ajax trys to call this index.php?type=450... with https and the page redirects to http...thats the problem.

Its a protocoll mixing. You know what I can do to prevent this on that page with this query string?

Thanks

btw. System is TYPO3 CMS 6.2.X

Comment: I would tell them that Google search prefers pages with https and that it would be a lot simpler if they forced the entire website to use https.
It would be better for their ranking in Google and the issue is solved automagically.

Comment: okay, thanks but they dont want it. I dont understand it, too.
You got an idea for a rewrite rule?